# Angular - Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<IUser, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular13

As I tried to create a user login feature in Angular-13, I have this model:

```js
export interface IUser {
   email: string;
   token: string;
}
```

Service:

```js
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(values: any) {
      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', values).pipe(
        map((user: IUser) => {
          if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
            this.currentUserSource.next(user);
          }
        })
      );
    }
}
```

I got this error while trying to implement it:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<IUser, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'

This is highlighted:

> map((user: IUser) => {

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you try making it any instead of IUser, this is not a fix, but just to understand if the problem is with the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you expect that your response returned is `IUser` type, then specify `T` as `IUser` type.

```js
post<T>(url: string, body: any, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; context?: HttpContext; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<T>
```

```js
login(values: any) {
  return this.http.post<IUser>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', values).pipe(
    map((user: IUser) => {
      ...
    })
  );
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h1phqv?file=src/app/account.service.ts)

---

### References

[`HttpClient post()` Overload #15](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)